# Invalid field permission field name Account field Account.billingstatecode

Tags: apex, metadata-api, error, custom-metadata

I am trying to add permissions to Account fields using Metadata Api.
I am receiving the error " Invalid field permission field name Account field Account.billingstatecode" and the permission set is not being created.
How do I resolve this

Thank you

```
public class AssignReadPermissionsBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>,Database.AllowsCallouts {
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        // collect the batches of records or objects to be passed to execute
       // String query='SELECT SObjectType From ObjectPermissions';
         String query = 'Select Name from DatalakeObjects__c';
         return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<DatalakeObjects__c> records){
        // process each batch of records
         
        List<MetadataService.PermissionSetObjectPermissions> objPermissions = new List<MetadataService.PermissionSetObjectPermissions>();
        List<MetadataService.PermissionSetFieldPermissions> fldPermissions = new List<MetadataService.PermissionSetFieldPermissions>();
        
        for (DatalakeObjects__c obj:records){
            
            //DescribeSObjectResult objDef = obj.getDescribe();
            MetadataService.PermissionSetObjectPermissions objPrmsn = new MetadataService.PermissionSetObjectPermissions();
            objPrmsn.object_x = obj.Name;
           // objPrmsn.allowRead = true;
            objPrmsn.allowCreate = false;
            objPrmsn.allowDelete = false;
            objPrmsn.allowEdit = false;
            objPrmsn.allowRead = true;
            objPrmsn.viewAllRecords = true;
            objPrmsn.modifyAllRecords = false;
            objPermissions.add(objPrmsn);
            //Map<String, SObjectField> fields = objDef.fields.getMap();
            //Set<String> fieldSet = fields.keySet();
            //List <String> fieldLst = Utilities.getFields(obj.Name);
            System.debug('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'+obj.Name);
            SObjectType objToken = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(obj.Name);
            
            DescribeSObjectResult objDef = objToken.getDescribe();
            Map<String, SObjectField> fields = objDef.fields.getMap(); 
             
            Set<String> fieldSet = fields.keySet();

            for(String fldName:fieldSet){
                SObjectField fieldToken = fields.get(fldName);
                DescribeFieldResult selectedField = fieldToken.getDescribe();
                if(selectedField.isPermissionable() && selectedField.isAccessible()){
                MetadataService.PermissionSetFieldPermissions fldPrmsn = new MetadataService.PermissionSetFieldPermissions();
                //fldPrmsn.field = selectedField.getName();
                fldPrmsn.field = obj.Name+'.'+fldName;
                fldPrmsn.readable = true;
                fldPrmsn.editable = false;
                fldPermissions.add(fldPrmsn);
                // fieldList.add(selectedField.getName());
                }
            }
            
        }//end of upper for
        MetadataService.PermissionSet ps = new MetadataService.PermissionSet();
        ps.fullName = 'Assign_ReadOnly';
        ps.label = 'AssignReadOnly_3';
        ps.objectPermissions = objPermissions;
        ps.fieldPermissions = fldPermissions;
        ps.hasActivationRequired = false;
        
        MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
        service.timeout_x = 60000;
        service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
        service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();
        
         MetadataService.Metadata[] mtDataList = new List<MetadataService.Metadata>();
         mtDataList.add(ps);
        
             
        List<MetadataService.SaveResult> results;
        if(!System.Test.isRunningTest()){
            results = service.createMetadata(mtDataList);
        }else {
            results = new List<MetadataService.SaveResult>();
            results[0].success = false;
            MetadataService.Error err = new MetadataService.Error();
            err.message = 'test';
            List<MetadataService.Error> errList = new List<MetadataService.Error>{err};
                results[0].errors = errList;
        }
        for(MetadataService.SaveResult res: results){
            System.debug(res.success);
            if(res.errors != null){
                for(MetadataService.Error err:res.errors){
                    System.debug('err mess '+err.message);
                }
                
            }
        }
    
        
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        // execute any post-processing operations
    }
}
```

Comment: `Billingstatecode` is a part of `billingstate`, could you try to grant access to that field instead?

Comment: No, I am looping through all the fields from Account using schema programming, the system is taking Billingstatecode only

Comment: Fair enough but I don't think you can restrict `billingstatecode` you will have to restrict `billingstate`.

Comment: Have you enabled state and country picklist in your org, as these field will be available only if the state and country picklists are activated

Comment: @jaferson How do I restrict billing state

Comment: You'll probably have to make a check in the loop for BillingStateCode and make and exception for that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a map and check for any overrides to the schema field names.

Something like this:

```
Map<String,String> fieldNameOverride = new Map<String,String>{
  'BillingStateCode'=>'BillingState'
};

//from your previous question
for(String fldName:fieldLst){

    //if there is an override, use that.
    fldName = fieldNameOverride.containsKey(fldName) ? fieldNameOverride.get(fldName) : fldName;
    
    MetadataService.PermissionSetFieldPermissions fldPrmsn = new MetadataService.PermissionSetFieldPermissions();
    fldPrmsn.field = fldName;
    fldPrmsn.readable = true;
    fldPrmsn.editable = false;
    fldPermissions.add(fldPrmsn);
}
```

This way, if you encounter anymore overrides, just add them to the `fieldNameOverride` Map.

Also, you might need to tweak this to put it in the format `ObjectApiName.FieldApiName`

Comment: I have pasted my code, could you please let me know where exactly the changes can be made